# Assert that an element contains a set of specific child elements in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to assert that a `<table>` element contains both a nested `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` element.

Sure, an obvious solution would be sth. like this:

```js
cy.get('table')
  .find('thead')

cy.get('table')
  .find('tbody')
```

but isn't there a simple way to to that all in one chain? Like this:

```js
cy.get('table')
  .should('contain.element','thead')
  .should('contain.element','tbody')
```

Unfortunatelly there is no such `contain.element`.

I know, there is `.should('contain.html','...')` but it doesn't work for me because this would require me to specify the full html string including nested content (with tr, td). I only want to assert that both child elements `thead` and `tbody` are existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery `.has()`

```js
cy.get('table')
  .should($table => {
    expect($table.has('thead')).to.eq(true)
    expect($table.has('tbody')).to.eq(true)
  })
```

---

Or same thing in one line

```js
cy.get('table:has(thead):has(tbody)')  // pseudo selector :has()
```

---

Or same thing in one selector

```js
cy.get('table thead, table tbody')     // jQuery Multiple Elements Selector
  .should('have.length', 2)            // passes if both exist
```

Comment: Great! Thx! 
```cy.get('table:has(thead):has(tbody)')``` is my favorite

Answer (score 0):

***Update:*** Okay, I missed your note, related `.should('contain.html'..)`. Usually, `contain.html` returns `true` if a node is a descendant of a target node, no matter if it has a deep three child nodes.

You can use `should` in combination with `and`. `.and()` yields the same subject it was given from the previous command:

```
cy.get('table')
  .should('contain.html','thead')
  .and('contain.html','tbody')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create an array of elements and using a `forEach()` loop assert that they are visible, something like this:

```js
const elements = ['table thead', 'table tbody']
elements.forEach((ele) => {
  cy.get(ele).should('be.visible')
})
```